# List Departments And Average Salary in Ascending Order of Average

Tags: oracle

I Created Table `Employee` And `Department`. `Employee` table contains employee details with salary and department id as foreign key.

I want to display List Departments And Average Salary in Ascending Order of Average.

The `department` table contains deptid and deptnm.

```
DEPTID(pk)    DEPTNM        DHEAD 
------------------------
1           COMPUTER      PATIL SIR 
2           MARATHI       PAWAR SIR 
3           MICRO         JADHAV SIR 
4           BIOTECH       BHOSALE SIR 
5           BOTANY        JADHAV SIR 

EMPID(pk) LASTNAME FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME   DOB      DOJ    SALARY EMPDEPTID 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      PAWAR    SIDDHANT  SANGHA     29-APR-97   02-JUL-15  10000     1   
2      ADKE     SHUBHAM   GIRISH     02-AUG-96   03-AUG-15  9000      2   
3      CHOUGULE NEERAJ    SUBHASH    01-MAR-94   05-DEC-15  7000      3  
4      MOTE     AJAY      SHAHAJI    05-JUN-96   10-NOV-15  4500      4   
5      SAHASTRA ASHWIN    MADAN      21-NOV-96   21-NOV-15  9000      5
```

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, choose it as the Accepted Answer, so other people know this question was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, you need to group by Department and calculate the average salary, sorting by it. Just in case `Department.DEPTNM` is not unique, we group by `DEPTID`:

```
SELECT Employee.EMPDEPTID, AVG(Employee.SALARY) as AVERAGE_SALARY 
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Department.DEPTID
ORDER BY AVG(Employee.SALARY)
```

If you need to get department names, then you can join to `Department` after:

```
SELECT * FROM (    

 SELECT Employee.EMPDEPTID, AVG(Employee.SALARY) as AVERAGE_SALARY 
 FROM Employee
 GROUP BY Department.DEPTID
 ORDER BY AVG(Employee.SALARY)

) as AVG_SALARY_PER_DEPT

JOIN Department ON (Department.DEPTID = AVG_SALARY_PER_DEPT.EMPLDEPTID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- [join](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm) your tables
- aggregate ([group by](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php))
- compute the [average](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions011.htm)
- [order by](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries005.htm) the average

In your case:

```
SELECT AVG(SALARY), DEPTID, DEPTNM, DHEAD
    FROM department
      INNER JOIN employee
        ON (DEPTID = EMPDEPTID)
GROUP BY DEPTID, DEPTNM, DHEAD
ORDER BY 1
```